# Particle effect displaying same particles -- not randomizing, Monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, particle-system

When I create particle effects, they all have the same pattern. They are rotated, but they all have the same pattern and same colored particles. See picture:

[image]

This is how a new ParticleEffect gets created:

```
ParticleEffect p = new ParticleEffect(textures, Vector2.Zero, destination, speed);
```

Where `textures` is a`Texture2D` list, VectorZero is the starting location, and so on.

Whenever a new `ParticleEffect` gets created it gets added to the `ParticleList` list, which later loops through all the items and calls `update` and `draw` for each effect inside.

Here is where the particles are randomised:

```
private Particle GenerateNewParticle()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    Texture2D texture = textures[random.Next(textures.Count)];
    Vector2 position = EmitterLocation;
    Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(
            1f * (float)(random.NextDouble() * 2 - 1),
            1f * (float)(random.NextDouble() * 2 - 1));
    float angle = 0;
    float angularVelocity = 0.1f * (float)(random.NextDouble() * 2 - 1);
    Color color = new Color(
            (float)random.NextDouble(),
            (float)random.NextDouble(),
            (float)random.NextDouble());
    float size = (float)random.NextDouble();
    int ttl = 20 + random.Next(40);

    return new Particle(texture, position, velocity, angle, angularVelocity, color, size, ttl);
}
```

A bunch of `randoms` there, but each effect still comes out the same. 
Comment if you want to see more code.

Edit:
Here is how a particle gets drawn:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, Texture.Width, Texture.Height);
    Vector2 origin = new Vector2(Texture.Width / 2, Texture.Height / 2);

    spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Position, sourceRectangle, Color,
        Angle, origin, Size, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `Random` instances are initiated with the current time as seed, that means the same sequence of numbers will be re-generated if you create instances at the same time - do not create new instances, reuse an existing instance to get more "randomized" behavior (in your case e.g. use a static `Random` instance).